# Error :The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want get picture of internet and insert into word .

I use this code .

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
System.Net.WebRequest request = 
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://spsdev2:1009");

System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
//Send an HTTP request and get the image at the URL as an HTTP response
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileName);
WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

//Get a stream from the webresponse
Stream stream = myResp.GetResponseStream();
```

I get error in  myReq.GetResponse();

Error :The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

**Edit**

This code work for me :)

```
myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;

myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12415619/465053) on another post worked for me.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I add credentials for `HttpWebRequest`.

```
myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Answer (score 9):

Shouldn't you be providing the credentials for your site, instead of passing the DefaultCredentials?

Something like `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "PassWord");`

Also, remove `request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; request.PreAuthenticate = true;`

Comment: Did you change it for a username and password that can actually access your site?

Comment: Can you remove the lines request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

Answer (score 0):

The answers did help, but I think a full implementation of this will help a lot of people.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Dom
{
    class Dom
    {
        public static string make_Sting_From_Dom(string reportname)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // Retrieve resource as a stream               
                Stream data = client.OpenRead(new Uri(reportname.Trim()));
                // Retrieve the text
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                string htmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                string mtch = "TILDE";
                bool b = htmlContent.Contains(mtch);

                if (b)
                {
                    int index = htmlContent.IndexOf(mtch);
                    if (index >= 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("'{0} begins at character position {1}",
                        mtch, index + 1);
                }
                // Cleanup
                data.Close();
                reader.Close();
                return htmlContent;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            make_Sting_From_Dom("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt");
        }
    }
}
```