# How to create a Push Notification (FCM) using C#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a REST Api written in .NET Core, now has a requirement to create a `Push Notification` to `Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)`. For testing, am using the `Firebase Console` but I need to get this done programtically. I have gone through the documentation of Firebase and some examples via Google but am more confused.

I think it is possible to create a message via a regular `Http` but can someone post a simple working example so that I can pick it up, please? Or maybe, my understanding is totally wrong?

Comment: you can now do it with the .net Admin SDK (no http), please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729521/4724142).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people have also liked this question, so thought of providing the solution I implemented, thinking it may help others. Please feel free to ask questions, if you have any.

**How to get the Server Key**: Here is the [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427709/firebase-messaging-where-to-get-server-key) which helps.

**Firebase Cloud Messaging Documentation** can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

```
public class FirebaseNotificationModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "to")]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "notification")]
    public NotificationModel Notification { get; set; }
}


using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
public static async void Send(FirebaseNotificationModel firebaseModel)
{
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = null;
    HttpClient httpClient = null;

    var authorizationKey = string.Format("key={0}", "YourFirebaseServerKey");
    var jsonBody = SerializationHelper.SerializeObject(firebaseModel);

    try
    {
        httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

        httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authorizationKey);
        httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        using (await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest))
        {
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        httpRequest.Dispose();
        httpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it's been 2.5 years since you posted this, but what about receiving something from a predefined topic?

Answer (score 5):

With .NET Core you can use this lightweight [CorePush library](https://github.com/andrei-m-code/CorePush) for Firebase Android, iOS, Web push notifications and Apple APN HTTP/2 Push notifications:

```
Install-Package CorePush
```

And then for Firebase Web, Android or iOS:

```
var firebaseSettingsJson = await File.ReadAllTextAsync('./project-123.json');
var fcm = new FirebaseSender(firebaseSettingsJson, httpClient);
await fcm.SendAsync(notification);
```

Or APN Apple Push Notifications via HTTP/2:

```
var apn = new ApnSender(settings, httpClient);
await apn.SendAsync(notification, deviceToken);
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, not making an http request