# Using VB.NET to sent notification to android emulator get error 401

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing VB.NET code to send notification to android Emulator. I can successfully send test message from the firebase control. However, it failed when I tried to send message via VB.NET code in my local machine and get error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized".

I have tried looking at the following link:
[FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Push Notification with Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184432/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-with-asp-net)
and following the instructions but it still not working.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Notification

    Public Sub SendNotification(ByVal deviceIDList As List(Of String), ByVal title As String, ByVal bodyMsg As String)

        Dim fcmPath As String = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
        Dim serverKey As String = "AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoCAeI"
        Dim senderID As String = "35xxxxxxx37"

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(fcmPath), HttpWebRequest)
        With request
            .Method = "POST"
            .ContentType = "application/json"
            .Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey))
            .Headers.Add(String.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderID))
        End With

        Using streamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            Dim webObject As New WebRequestFcmData
            With webObject
                .registration_ids = deviceIDList
                .notification.title = title
                .notification.body = bodyMsg
                .notification.content_available = True
                .notification.sound = "default"
                .notification.priority = "high"
            End With
            Dim body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webObject)
            With streamWriter
                .Write(body)
                .Flush()
                .Close()
            End With
        End Using
        Dim httpResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Using streamReader As New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream)
            Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class WebRequestFcmData
    Public Property registration_ids As List(Of String)
    Public Property notification As New NotificationData
End Class

Public Class NotificationData
    Public Property body As String
    Public Property content_available As Boolean
    Public Property priority As String
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property sound As String
End Class
```

The error occurred at the line:

```
Dim httpResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Here is the server key and sender ID that I use:
[image]

Updated:
I tried sending web request from Postman application and it also gave the same error (401: Unauthorized) as shown in the figure below:

[image: Posting Web Request Failed]

Comment: which error do you get? you should at least write Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) and use response instead of httpResponse

Comment: I got the error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." It still occur even though I fixed the code as you mentioned.

Comment: 401 means your account data is not valid. you should check id and server key

Comment: OK. I have made a silly mistake by looking for the key in the wrong place. Now, I found the solution and updated the answer. Thank you nbk for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I made a silly mistake by using API Key which is not actual Server key. Even though I have read that I should go to cloud messaging tab in project setting, I misunderstood that I have to look in cloud messaging tab in the side bar which is wrong. Here is the step where I found server key:

1. Click on the setting button near Project Overview

   [image]
2. Choose the first option (Project setting)

   [image]
3. Click on the second tab (Cloud messaging)

   [image]
4. Use the server key and sender ID in this page

   [image]

At first, I tried looking for server key in cloud messaging tab in the sidebar which is wrong location.

[image]