# Xamarin.Forms using Firebase Cloud Message to send notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm need to send my Web API notification when user order something on my app, but i dont know how to send Notification to Firebase on Xamarin.Forms.

Does anyone have some sample or source code to follow ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184432/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the Notification in specific Xamarin.Android project and Xamarin.iOS project.

For **Xamarin.Android**:

You can have a look at official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging) and [Remote Notifications with Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows), there are step-by-step explanations of how to use `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to implement remote notifications (also called push notifications) in a `Xamarin.Android` application.

For **Xamarin.iOS**:

You can use [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging/) to send iOS push notification by FCM.

There are also steps here: [Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/docs/Firebase/CloudMessaging/GettingStarted.md#about-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Firebase document for push notification to native app is here: [cloud-messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)