# How to push a notification to Android and iOS (Xamarin.Forms) from desktop application using Firebase?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, desktop-application

We want to send a notification to Xamarin.Forms (android and ios) devices from a desktop application.
I understand that to push notifications to Android, Google's Firebase is required. I found information on how to link android and ios with Firebase and send notifications from the Firebase console page, but we want to send notifications outside the Firebase website. Is there some sort of API call to firebase to instruct it to send it?

Also, why would we need Azure Notification Hub that has a cost to it, as it keeps coming up in Google results?

Any additional information would be helpful.

Comment: You could use `Cloud Messaging` . Here is a similar question maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496135/xamarin-forms-using-firebase-cloud-message-to-send-notification .

Comment: Kidnly refer to this link. [https://medium.com/@prabhanu96/firebase-push-notification-testing-using-postman-393bd171659#:~:text=First%2C%20follow%20the%20below%20steps,Authorization%20and%20Content%2DType%20headers.]