# Notification sent from backend not appearing on Firebase Console

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm able to send notifications from the [console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) to mobile devices and from my backend API written in **.NET Core 3.1** using the [FirebaseAdmin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAdmin/) package as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184432/fcm-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notification-with-asp-net). The message arrives successfully from either source.

The thing is that when the notification is sent by the backend API, it doesn't show up in the **Notifications** tab that you can see in the console ([https://console.firebase.google.com/project/>**PROJECT-ID](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/%3E**PROJECT-ID)**</notification) and I was wondering why.

To illustrate this, here are 5 notifications sent through the *New notification* button a couple of months ago. All of them appear on the table.

[image]

But then, if you go to the **Reports** tab you'll see 6 notifications, the last one was sent today using C#.

[image]

I would like that all the notifications appear in the **Notifications** table, even those sent from the backend. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like that all the notifications appear in the Notifications table, even those sent from the backend. Is that possible?

You have no control over this as far as I know. If the notifications sent through the API don't show up in the Firebase console, there is nothing you can do to change that behavior.

I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). While I expect others will have filed this feature request before, it never hurts to chime in that you'd like to see this too.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I suspected that. I'm going to wait a little bit for other answers in the meantime.