# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized on Pay Fabric service

Tags: c#

I am using below code to get token from pay fabric service. But I am facing an error while doing so: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized".
Have been doing net searching for several hours but didn't find something helpful.

```
        var url = "https://sandbox.payfabric.com/payment/api/token/create";
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["authorization"] = "DeviceID/Password";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

        //at this line I am getting error.           
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        //

        Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        httpWebRequest.Abort();
        httpWebResponse.Close();

        // Parse JSON response
        TokenResponse obj = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<TokenResponse>(result);
        return obj.Token;
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205854/error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized

Comment: Yes I tried it but it didn't work for me. Still same error.