# C# HttpWebRequest does not work with my URL in MAUI app while URL works without any problem in browser directly or via PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, visual-studio, maui

When I try to load data from the URL I get:

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

My Code in MAUI app:

```
var url = "http://somedomen.com/GetDataCSV.php?GetDataCSV=&type=xml";

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The URL works very well in PHP:

```
$products = file_get_contents("http://somedomen.com/GetDataCSV.php?GetDataCSV=&type=xml"); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($products);
```

It works very well in a browser directly without any authorization.

What I am doing wrang and how to solve the problem?

Comment: you need to check the server logs or ask the server admin why it's returning 401.  It could be anything - the server can return any error code it wants, even if it has nothing to do with authentication

Comment: What happens when you issue a `GET` request without the query parameters? `HttpClient client = new(); var response = await client.GetAsync("http://somedomen.com/GetDataCSV.php");`

Comment: @WBuck the result is as bellow: 

response = Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = {null}

Comment: Thanks, @Jason , I will ask the admin to help me too.

Comment: @Luka You need to `await` the call.. What you have isn't a response but a `Task`

Comment: @WBuck, I have done it with "await" and the response is null

Comment: It may be rejecting your user-agent. Use the network tab of your browser dev tools to trace the request and response, then recreate that request in c#.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried it but does not work.

Comment: Which platform did you test on?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Android and Windows as well

Comment: You can try the answer in [this case which met the same problem as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205854/error-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized).

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Unfortunately it does not work for me

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You can try to access some other web api to test if the casue is the web site or not.